# Convert CSV list to Set<Long> with no duplicates, ignore nulls

Tags: java

I'd like to convert a list of numbers in a string that are separated by commas, into a `Set<Long>` in java, ignoring null entries and duplicates. The delimiter could be any string, not just a comma, but I'm using a comma here for simplicity.

e.g.

```
// NOTE: Edited to add "   " case
String csv = "1,2,3,  ,4,,2";  
Set<Long> set = `???`
```

and now `set` should contain

**Output**

```
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java 8 solution is the following:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;

String csv = "1,2,3,4,,2";
Set<Long> set = Arrays.asList(csv.split(","))
        .stream()
        .map(String::trim)
        .filter(x -> x.length() > 0)
        .map(Long::parseLong)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Could use `Arrays.stream(csv.split("\\D+"))` to avoid creating a list and filtering the empty strings.

Comment: trim is not neccesary, however you might want to use `split(",", -1)` instead. And in filter you could create a predicate         `Predicate<String> emptyString = String::isEmpty;` and use `emptyString.negate()` on it

Comment: @ViktorMellgren - thanks for the feedback - but the trim is necessary for the case where there's a null entry with multiple spaces, e.g. "1,  ,2". At least it seemed to be, as I tried removing the trim, and/or the filter and both failed.

Answer (score 1):

Also another approach in one `for loop` with one `if-statement` (if the user does not want using `Stream` or availing of Java 8 new features):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConvertCSVToSETLong {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // different numbers of commas
        String csv = "1,,,,2,3,,,,4,,,,2,,5,,6,7,1"; 
        Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();

        for(String s : csv.split(",")){
            if(!s.trim().isEmpty()){
              set.add(Long.parseLong(s));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(set); // test
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Scanner

```
    String csv = "1,2,3,4,,2";
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(csv)) {
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String next = sc.next();
            if (!next.equals("")) {
                set.add(Long.parseLong(next));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(set);
```